# `git merge` reports conflicts for files that I have not changed

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I'd like to understand what's going on with the following (attempted) git merge.

I have a fork of llvm where the `main` branch is upstream's `llvmorg-12.0.0` tag, plus:

- Two new files.
- Two small changes to existing upstream files.

We can see the files I've touched in my branch by doing this:

```
$ git diff --name-only llvmorg-12.0.0
.buildbot.sh # new file
bors.toml    # new file
llvm/CMakeLists.txt # modified file
llvm/lib/CodeGen/AsmPrinter/AsmPrinter.cpp # modified file
```

And here's what my `main` branch looks like in `tig`:
[image]

Now I want to sync to the latest llvm release into my branch, i.e. the `llvmorg-13.0.0` tag. I've already done `git fetch llvm` to get all of upstream's commits and tags.

Let's start by making a branch to do the merge in:

```
$ git co -b sync-llvm13
Switched to a new branch 'sync-llvm13'
```

Now let's do the merge:

```
$ git merge llvmorg-13.0.0
Performing inexact rename detection: 100% (8537886/8537886), done.                                                                                                                                 
warning: Cannot merge binary files: llvm/test/tools/llvm-profgen/Inputs/recursion-compression-pseudoprobe.perfbin (HEAD vs. llvmorg-13.0.0)                                                        
Removing polly/lib/External/isl/cpp/cpp.h.pre                                                                                                                                                      
Removing polly/lib/External/isl/cpp/cpp-checked.h.pre                                                                                                                                              
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in openmp/runtime/test/tasking/hidden_helper_task/capacity_nthreads.cpp                                                                                         
Auto-merging openmp/runtime/test/tasking/hidden_helper_task/capacity_nthreads.cpp                                                                                                                  
Removing openmp/runtime/src/tsan_annotations.h                                                                                                                                                     
Removing openmp/runtime/src/tsan_annotations.cpp                                                                                                                                                   
Auto-merging openmp/runtime/src/kmp_tasking.cpp                                                                                                                                                    
Auto-merging openmp/runtime/src/kmp_settings.cpp                                                                                                                                                   
Auto-merging openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp                                                                                                                                                    
Auto-merging openmp/runtime/src/kmp_config.h.cmake                                                                                                                                                 
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in openmp/runtime/src/kmp_config.h.cmake                                                                                                                        
Auto-merging openmp/runtime/src/CMakeLists.txt                                                                                                                                                     
Auto-merging openmp/runtime/cmake/config-ix.cmake                                                                                                                                                  
Auto-merging openmp/runtime/CMakeLists.txt                                                                                                                                                         
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in openmp/libomptarget/test/offloading/bug49334.cpp                                                                                                             
Auto-merging openmp/libomptarget/test/offloading/bug49334.cpp                                                                                                                                      
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in openmp/libomptarget/test/offloading/bug49021.cpp                                                                                                             
Auto-merging openmp/libomptarget/test/offloading/bug49021.cpp                                                                                                                                      
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in openmp/libomptarget/test/offloading/assert.cpp
...
Auto-merging clang/test/Preprocessor/riscv-target-features.c                                                                                                                                       
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in clang/test/Preprocessor/riscv-target-features.c                                                                                                              
Removing clang/test/Preprocessor/pragma_sysheader.h                                                                                                                                                
Auto-merging clang/test/Preprocessor/macro_vaopt_check.cpp                                                                                                                                         
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in clang/test/Preprocessor/macro_vaopt_check.cpp                                                                                                                
Auto-merging clang/test/OpenMP/teams_distribute_simd_codegen.cpp                                                                                                                                   
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in clang/test/OpenMP/teams_distribute_simd_codegen.cpp                                                                                                          
Auto-merging clang/test/OpenMP/teams_distribute_parallel_for_simd_codegen.cpp                                                                                                                      
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in clang/test/OpenMP/teams_distribute_parallel_for_simd_codegen.cpp                                                                                             
Auto-merging clang/test/OpenMP/teams_distribute_parallel_for_codegen.cpp                                                                                                                           
...loads more conflicts
```

This comes as a surprise. There are loads of files marked as conflicting, but which I've never touched.

The conflicts are a mix of `add/add`, `rename/delete` and `content`.

Looking at one of the `content` conflicts there are indeed conflict markers in the file (e.g. `libcxx/include/__support/openbsd/xlocale.h`):

```
...
<<<<<<< HEAD:libcxx/include/__support/openbsd/xlocale.h                                                                                                                                        
#include <__support/xlocale/__strtonum_fallback.h>                                                                                                                                             
=======                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <cwctype>                                                                                                                                                                             
>>>>>>> llvmorg-13.0.0:libcxx/include/support/openbsd/xlocale.h
...
```

(So this rules out line endings as a cause)

I'm confused. As shown above with the `git diff --only-name` command, I've never edited these files.

What's gong on?

User error/misconception? Should I have merged a different way?

This is using the latest git (2.33.0) on Debian 11.

Comment: See TTT's answer for details, but: just because *you* didn't change some files, doesn't mean that they haven't been changed (since some common starting point). Merge means *combine work* and you're trying to combine other peoples' (plural) work that they chose not to combine themselves, probably because there was no point in doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This could be explained if tag `llvmorg-12.0.0` is not reachable by tag `llvmorg-13.0.0`.**

In other words, checkout tag 12, and try to merge in tag 13, and you may get conflicts. If you do it (obviously) has nothing to do with your code, it just means that that the branching strategy the maintainers of that repo use doesn't necessarily include merging released tags back into `main`. Or if they eventually do, they didn't do it between those two releases.

You could also test if tag 12 is reachable from tag 13 with this command (in Git Bash or a *nix shell):

```
git rev-list llvmorg-13.0.0 | grep `git rev-parse llvmorg-12.0.0`
```

The "rev-list" part of the command lists all commits reachable from tag 13, and then it greps to see if tag 12's commit ID is one of them.

If that outputs nothing, then this is exactly what is happening.

From your merge output, the lines you see with `CONFLICT (add/add)` suggests that the repo maintainers cherry-picked some commits from the release-12 branch back into `main` or the release-13 branch instead of merging, which is additional proof this is the reason. That strategy means that release tags are not reachable from each other, and that merge conflicts could arise if you merge one release tag into another.

**So what should you do?**

Two possible options are:

**1.** Branch off of `main` (original main, not your fork- maybe keep yours synced?) and keep rebasing onto `main` until you're ready to do *something else* with your code. With your branch checked out, rebuild your branch like this:

```
git rebase --onto main llvmorg-12.0.0
```

Subsequent rebases would be regular: `git rebase main`

**2.** Rebuild your branch off of the newer tag instead of merging in the newer tag. With your branch checked out, rebuild your branch like this:

```
git rebase --onto llvmorg-13.0.0 llvmorg-12.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had mistakenly thought that llvm releases where just tags on the main branch. Not so! I wonder if there's a solution that would allow me to keep my git history (i.e. without rebasing)?

Comment: For example, I had hoped to generate a merge commit from llvmorg-12.0.0 to llvmorg-13.0.0 by starting with a branch at llvmorg-12.0.0 and doing `git merge -X theirs llvmorg-13.0.0`. I could then cherry-pick this on top of our forks main branch. Alas, the merge command doesn't have the desired effect :\

Comment: @EddBarrett If your commits were part of the tagged release, then they would have been cherry-picked over into the new release like everything else. So I'm not sure that it makes sense to keep your git history by doing merges between tags in this repo, since the repo maintainers apparently don't want tags merged into each other. This is why I suggested the rebase, which is mimicking what the maintainers of the repo do. BTW, the rebase doesn't mean you have to have only one branch. You could have one branch with your additions, per tagged release, like the repo does. When in Rome... :)

Comment: Note if you keep separate branches per release, I guess that would count as "keeping your git history". Or, you could add your own tags to each of your updated releases and then you don't have to keep all the release branches around. For example, tag each of your improved releases in your own repo with `llvmorg-12.0.0-EB`,  `llvmorg-13.0.0-EB`, etc.